# Carregar formulário com campos desabilitados ao clicar em botão

Tags: javascript, jquery

Gostaria de fazer uma função em js, que ao clicar em um botão de visualizar, ao direcionar para a página, carregue meu formulário com todos os meus campos desabilitados, de forma que o usuário não consiga alterar nada. 
Como posso fazer?

Comment: Qual é a parte que  precisas de ajuda? `$('#idDaForm :input').attr('readonly','readonly');` deve chegar para pôr tudo readonly. É isto que procuras? -> http://jsfiddle.net/nuxxf9Lr/

Comment: Meu botao visualizar esta em uma pagina index:                                td(style='text-align: center') 
    a(class="btn btn-search", id="staff" href="staffs/#{staff._id}")
        i.halflings-icon.white.search                                                                        Ao ser clicado, direciona para o endereço acima, porém necessito que ao direcionar para esta pagina, o formulário venha desabilitado.

Comment: Acho que tens de [edit] e clarificar a pergunta um pouco mais. O formulário está numa página diferente que o botão? como queres ir buscar esse HTML? Explica também um pouco melhor a funcionalidade que queres par percebermos melhor o que procuras.

Comment: você precisa "instanciar" seu form em um novo form, e esse segundo form precisa estar com todos os campos desabilitados correto? esse segundo form precisa ser instanciado em pop-up ou em uma nova aba do navegador?